# Remove both path and extension from string in Lua

Tags: string, lua, path, filenames, lua-patterns

I'm trying to get the name of the file without the path and the extension in one go. I am using `string.match` and `([^\\/]+)$` to get rid of the path and then another `string.match` with `(.+)%.[^.]+$` to get rid of the extension. This works but I was wondering if there's a way to get rid of both of them using `string.match` only once. Any way to combine the two regex codes?

I've tried various other regex codes on the internet but it seems that Lua doesn't play well with all of them.

In practice:

```
entirepath = "C:/Users/mail/Desktop/Something/Test.mp3"

justname = string.match(entirepath, "code that keeps only filename")

print(justname)
```

Result should be `Test`.

Comment: FYI, Lua doesn't use regex; it has its own equivalent that goes by the name of "*[Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```lua
local path = "/path/to/your/file/filename.txt"
local filename, extension = path:match("^.+/(.+)%.(.+)$")

print("Filename: " .. filename)
print("Extension: " .. extension)
```

Comment: Re *"You can try this"*: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77810559/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).